# How to Add MVC @item.ModuleName FOR Action Link

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm Develop the MVC project ,I can't add my @item.ModuleName for Action link, how can i add it? im try to this but not correct solution, please help me
thanks

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ModuleList)
    {
        <tr style="color:#000000; height:5px;">
           <td height="45px;">
               @item.ModuleName
               @Html.ActionLink("Go and Set", "ViewModule", "UserRegistration", new { idd = item.ModuleId, A = "Set" }, new { Class = "btn btn-info", style = " line-height:10px;left:3px;background-color:#24ade3; position:relative; width:65px;" })
           </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink(@item.ModuleName, "ViewModule",.....`

Comment: Thanks for the help, Im added your solution, its not work ,

Comment: @Html.ActionLink(@item.ModuleName, "ViewModule", "UserRegistration", new { idd = item.ModuleId, A = "Set" }, new { Class = "btn btn-info", style = " line-height:10px;left:3px;background-color:#24ade3; position:relative; width:65px;" })</td>

Comment: What's wrong with `@Html.ActionLink(item.ModuleName,...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parameter of action link is the name of action link so add @item.ModuleName as the first parameter and it will display the link with module name. like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(@item.ModuleName,
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.ModuleName,....
```